# Yii2. Pjax and Session

Tags: php, yii, yii2

For testing reasons, I am trying to use Pjax in a widget. In the view:

```
$testArgs = [
            'param' => 'test'
        ];
Yii::$app->session->set('testArgs', $testArgs);
echo Test::widget($testArgs);
```

Then in the widget:

```
class Test extends Widget {

    public $param;
    ..

    public function init() {
      ..
    }

    public function run() {

        Pjax::begin();

        echo "<a href='test/add'>[ + ]</a> | <a href='test/remove'>[ - ]</a>";

        Pjax::end();
    }
}
```

Then in TestController:

```
public function actionAdd() {
   $testArgs = Yii::$app->session->get('testArgs');
   var_dump($testArgs);
   die;
 }
```

$testArgs is NULL. Why? Pjax creates a different session?

**UPDATE 1**

I have added an echo with session_id() and it seems is same session

**UPDATE 2**

In the real widget I am passing to session a $form (ActiveForm) object. I think this is the issue. I tried to serialize it, but it returned an error saying "Closure can not be serialized"

**UPDATE 3**

It seems that closure serialization is a well known error in PHP reviewing how to by pass that, since I can not remove the closures from the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question. No, PJax does not create a different session. Adding form object to my session is breaking it, I will open a different question for this.