# Yii2. Session and Forms

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to set a $form object (from ActiveForm) in session:

```
$fofArgs = [
           'form' => $form,
        ];
 Yii::$app->session->set('fofArgs', $fofArgs);
```

But When I call in an action:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get('fofArgs'));
```

It prints NULL. My guess is that is related to closures, since I tried to serialize $form and I got an error "Closures can not be serialized".

Any ideas?

This is a question after I thought it was an error with pJax: [Yii2. Pjax and Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418732/yii2-pjax-and-session)

**UPDATE**

Please test doing

```
Yii::$app->session->set('formtest', $form)
```

in one controller/action and then

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get('formtest'));
```

in a different one, if you do it in the same it seems it works.

Comment: I was able to set the form object in session and accessed it in the action. Using your same code !!!

Comment: In one occasion I got NULL when printed out the session variable , but it was because I got logged out of some reason and session was reset. Otherwise your code is working

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the model you used to create your form, has rules? it seems it fails when it has rules because those are represented as closures.

Comment: Yup. Its a login form and the model has rules.

Comment: Can I ask whether this is  a general query or are you trying to achieve something ??

Comment: @ck_arjun I have tested again and same issue. I have set session with form in one controller/action and trying to get it in another one and result is NULL. I am already logged in and other session vars works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was that sessions are internally serialized in Yii, so it is not possible to save an object with closures.

Everyday we learn something new.